# Анимация построенная на времени

Tags: actionscript-3, разработка-игр, flash, java, анимация

Только недавно понял принцип работы анимации построенной на времени и сейчас захотел её применить. Применить не просто, а построить на её основе анимацию ( равномерно текущего времени ) для всего приложения. То есть, установить в главном классе, рассчитывающем время, что то типа самописного твина, но не могу придумать, как это сделать.
Я знаю, что многие пользуются таким подходом и знают, как это реализовать. 
Если можно, обьясните пожалуйста, что для этого нужно, сам принцип очень хочется разобрать.
Если кто то строчкой кода покажет, против не буду.

Comment: Буду рад, если кто нибудь поделится ссылками на статьи описывающие мой вопрос или ещё чему нибудь. И не жадничайте :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Привет.

В сильно упрощенном виде.

Делаем так:

```
// ActionScript 3 (Flash)
// Сохраняем время на старте анимации.
var startTime:int = getTimer(); // Отсчет в миллисекундах.
// Задаем скорость анимации, скажем 1 градус угла поворота в 100 миллисекунд.
var speed:Number = 100;
// Подписываемся на обновление объекта раз в кадр.
object.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler )

private function enterFrameHandler( e:Event ):void
{
    // Получаем текущее и вычисляем прошедшее время.
    var time:int = getTimer() - startTime;
    // Угол поворота за прошедшее время.
    var angle:Number = time / speed;
    // Теперь можно повернуть.
    object.rotation = angle;
}
```

Comment: @ShockWave: Спасибо Вам! но Вы меня немного не так поняли. Как сделать выдачу времени я знаю. При таком подходе плавности не будет, так как скорость rotation всё так же зависит от выданного времени. Если его чуть больше, то скорость поворота больше и наоборот. А я спрашиваю, как на основе этого подхода сделать плавную анимацию ( или максимально приближенной к плавной ).
У твинов же работа на getTimer строится и они проигрывают движение без лагов и плюс к скорости, они же и рендер контролируют. Значит как они скорость с кадрами контролируют.

Comment: - при таком подходе плавность обеспечена
- зависимость скорости от времени это нормально, так как время работы приложения не зависит например от частоты кадров или других параметров
- времени не может быть больше или меньше, за 1 сек, получаете 1000мс, за 10 сек - 10к
- эта анимация проигрывается без лагов в условиях сферического вакуума
- твинеры не контролируют рендер, стандартный твинер меняет параметры объекту анимации, рендером обычно занимается какая то другая сущность, во флеше это так называемый Display List
- скорость с кадрами контролировать можно, но в данном случае это не важно